# プログラムから別のアプリを起動する

Tags: swift, ios

Swiftを使ってiOSアプリを作成しています。
自分のアプリにボタンを作り、そこから別のアプリを起動させたいと考えているのですが、やり方がわかりません。（URLスキームというワードがちらほら）
ちなみに、ボタンをタップした時に起動させる別のアプリは、AppStoreでインストールできる画像をコラージュできるようなアプリを指定する予定です。

（補足）
回答者さまのヒントを元に、以下のサイトを試しているのですがうまく実行できません。
ただコードを真似るだけだと
「Use of undeclared type 'NSWorkspace'」というエラーが出ます。
どこかでNSWorkspaceを宣言しないといけないのだと思うのですが、具体的にどこに宣言したらいいのか、コード以外でも設定すべきことはあるのかわかる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。

http://cocoaapi.hatenablog.com/entry/00000111/recID34975

Comment: 言語名だけでプラットフォーム名が示されていませんが、どちらでしょうか?_ applestore_とありますのでまさかLinuxではないと思いますが、ご記載の内容だけではiOSなのかmacOSなのか(可能性は低いでしょうがtvOS, watchOSなんかもあります)わかりません。また _勉強不足なのは承知していますが、急ぎのためこの場をお借りします。_ とありますが、「急ぎ」であるなら何をやっても許されるというものではありません。_URLスキーム_ と言う言葉までたどり着かれているのですから、それなりの時間をかけてお調べになったのだと思います。「急ぎのため」なんて1行を書く暇があったら、見つけた記事のリンク(オンラインのものなら)を掲載した方が多少はマシなアピールになるでしょう。と言うわけで **プラットフォーム名(iOSかmacOSか)を明記してください** **参考にした記事リンクや書籍名を挙げて、どうわからないのかをもう少し具体的に記述**してください。(「具体的な手順がわからない」「この記事内容が目的にために使えるのかわからない」なんかでも「イマイチわかりません」よりははるかにマシです)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。訂正・補足をしてみましたが、他にも気になる点があれば再度ご指摘お願いします！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLスキームというのはCustomURLSchemeのことかとおもわれます。
Androidなどではディープリンクとも言ったりします。

例えば次のリンクをiOSのSafariにてURL欄に打ち込むと写真アプリが起動します。
`photos-redirect://`

これは写真アプリのSchemeに"photos-redirect"という名称でスキーム(Scheme)が登録されているからです。
これらはアプリごとにスキームが設定されています。
設定の初期値は"Bundle ID"(jp.com.xxxxxxx)になりますが、
独自に名称を設定すると`appname://`のような名称をSchemeに設定できます。

話を戻しますと、URLSchemeで起動を行おうと思った場合、
対象のアプリで設定されているSchemeを知らなくてはいけません。
ですので、自作アプリか、他の別の方のアプリかで話が変わってきます。
Schemeの調査の説明になると長くなるので自作アプリであることを前提でお話します。

---

1. CustomURLSchemeの設定

アプリのplistファイルにてURLSchemeの設定を行うことが出来ます。
plistファイル内を"Schemes"で検索すると下記のような項目があるので2箇所確認して修正しましょう。
下記を設定すると`スキーム名://`で開くことが出来るようになります。

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>【アプリBundleID】</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>【スキーム名】</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

---

2. CustomURLSchemeを開く

普通のURLと同じように扱います。
下記でCustomURLSchemeを開くことが出来る……のですが、
もう1つ設定が必要で後述します。

```
let url = NSURL(string: "スキーム名://")!
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

---

3. plistファイルで連携するアプリのCustomURLSchemeを登録する

最近のアップデートだったと思うのですが、
連携するアプリのSchemeを設定しないと外部アプリへ遷移することが出来ません。
ですので、開く前に下記の設定をplistファイルで行いましょう。

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>スキーム名</string>
</array>
```

Comment: 丁寧な説明ありがとうございます。URLスキームというワードまでたどり着いたものの設定の仕方がわからず困っていたのですが、おかげで無事にアプリを連携させることができました！本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

アプリケーション名が既知で固定であれば、

```
NSWorkspace.shared().launchApplication("アプリケーション名")
```

ではいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。まだ実装できてないのでNSWorkspaceクラスについて更に調べてみます！また、補足を追加したので良ければそちらにも目を通していただければと思います。

Comment: 補足を読みました。上記はmacOSでの手法のため、iOSでは使えません。申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: 自分がプラットフォーム名を書き忘れてたミスなので、申し訳ないです。回答ありがとうございました！